# Direct proportion - sum of numbers and square root of sum of the squared numbers

Tags: inequality, radicals

Is it true for all the cases that if $x + y > a+b$, then $\sqrt{x^2 + y^2} > \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$? In other words - is there a direct proportion between sum of numbers and square root of the sum of those numbers squared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, take $x=y=3,a=5,b=0$, then $x+y=6, a+b=5, \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt {18} =3\sqrt 2\approx 4.242, \sqrt{a^2+b^2}=5$

Answer (score 0):

A more easy example to notice is if $x=y=1$ and $a=b=-2.$ Then you have: $$2=x+y\lt a+b=-4\quad\color{grey}{\text{but}}\quad \sqrt{x^2+y^2}=\sqrt2<\sqrt{(-2)^2+(-2)^2}=\sqrt{8}.$$

Comment: thanks! As soon as I am able to upvote, I'll upvote this!

Comment: Thanks @Dundee $\overset{\cdot\cdot}\smile$